2024 IRS Filing for Deceased Spouse
IRS Interactive Tax Assistance tells how the Surviving Spouse can file joint return
Surviving Spouse is filing paper return and is due a refund.
IRS says (I took screenshot of PDF since I am unable to upload document)

Write the word "Deceased", the decedent's name, and the date of death across the top of the tax return

Two questions

Does the return include the name, date of birth, ssn of the deceased spouse. This information was included in previous years when deceased spouse was alive

In past years, both spouses signed the return. Since the deceased spouse is no more, what should be written in the section where the deceased spouse used to write and sign their name


I am unable to find this information IRS website. Please help.




Does the return include the name, date of birth, ssn of the deceased spouse. This information was included in previous years when deceased spouse was alive

Yes, absolutely. If you're filing a joint return - it has to be joint with someone else.

In past years, both spouses signed the return. Since the deceased spouse is no more, what should be written in the section where the deceased spouse used to write and sign their name

The instructions say to "Write the word "Deceased", the decedent's name, and the date of death across the top of the tax return". Further down the screenshot it also says "and write in the signature area "Filing as surviving spouse"".
Since it would be paper-filed, someone will have to manually enter it into the system and will see it.
